# SQL Combining two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below code selects records from the two tables where both the email and dob match another record (all duplicates..)

```
SELECT 
    AccountName, 
    EmailAddress, 
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        a.AccountName, 
        a.EmailAddress, 
        u.DateOfBirth, 
        COUNT(*) over (partition by a.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth) AS cnt
    FROM Account AS a 
    JOIN [User] AS u ON a.AccountID = u.AccountID              
) ua                
WHERE cnt > 1
AND EmailAddress IS NOT null
AND DateOfBirth IS NOT null     
ORDER BY EmailAddress, DateOfBirth
```

I also want to add to this table, a field within another table called 'Audit'. We can join them using the LoginID, however the LoginID has a one to many relationship in the Audit table. i.e. a LoginID can have many Audits.

I want to add the Audit StartDate column. The following query allows me to identify the latest Audit by date.

```
         SELECT  a.LoginID as AuditLoginID,
         MAX(StartDate) as StartDate
         FROM    Audit as a
         GROUP BY  a.LoginID
         ORDER BY a.StartDate
```

Would anyone be able to suggest how I can combine these two queries, so that my original query has a join to the Audit table, displaying a 'StartDate' column of the latest audit start date?

Comment: I would suggest creating a VIEW from your second query. And update the first query to join with the VIEW.

Comment: could you post some relevant data? enough for us to work with?

Comment: Yeah it's actually kind of hard to answer this without some example data....

Comment: i agree with @MikyDinescu try to create a view is the best solution for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using a [correlated subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/correlated-subqueries.html).  That will avoid building another database object to support this query, and it's a relatively standard SQL construct.

Example:

```
SELECT 
    AccountName, 
    EmailAddress, 
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        a.AccountName, 
        a.EmailAddress, 
        u.DateOfBirth, 
        a.LoginID,
        COUNT(*) over (partition by a.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth) AS cnt
    FROM Account AS a 
    JOIN [User] AS u ON a.AccountID = u.AccountID              
) ua           
join Audit as a 
  on a.LoginID = au.LoginID     
WHERE cnt > 1
AND EmailAddress IS NOT null
AND DateOfBirth IS NOT null     
AND a.startdate = (SELECT MAX(StartDate) as StartDate
                   FROM    Audit as b
                   WHERE b.LoginID = a.LoginID)
ORDER BY EmailAddress, DateOfBirth
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an expansion on my comment:

```
CREATE VIEW MostRecentLogins AS
  (
     SELECT a.LoginID as AuditLoginID,
            MAX(StartDate) as StartDate
       FROM Audit as a
      GROUP BY a.LoginID
  )
```

Then, you can join the `MostRecentLogins` view into your other query. It's not clear from your post which column would be the counterpart to `LoginId` (from the `Audit` table) but the query would then look something like this:

```
SELECT a.AccountName, 
       a.EmailAddress, 
       u.DateOfBirth,
       MRL.StartDate
  FROM 
     (
       SELECT a.AccountName, 
              a.EmailAddress, 
              u.DateOfBirth, 
              COUNT(*) over (partition by a.EmailAddress, u.DateOfBirth) AS cnt
         FROM Account AS a 
              JOIN [User] AS u 
                       ON a.AccountID = u.AccountID              
     ) ua
     INNER JOIN MostRecentLogins MRL
         ON MRL.LoginID = a.LoginID    -- not sure what column should be on the RHS of this..
  WHERE cnt > 1
    AND EmailAddress IS NOT null
    AND DateOfBirth IS NOT null     
  ORDER BY EmailAddress, DateOfBirth
```